# System folder & database.php path

Tags: php, database, path

I moved my system folder above the root and was updating the database.php file and was confused about the correct path for one of the settings.

Should it be:

$db['expressionengine']['cachedir'] = '/nfs/c10/h06/mnt/143832/domains/website.org/**html**/system/expressionengine/cache/db_cache/';

or

$db['expressionengine']['cachedir'] = '/nfs/c10/h06/mnt/143832/domains/website.org/system/expressionengine/cache/db_cache/';

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the root of your site is "/nfs/c10/h06/mnt/143832/domains/website.org/html/", the right option is the second one.

Comment: I am just wondering if cache directory is above the root or "public html", will it be still writable?

Comment: Hi, @BhashkarYadav! In all server I had permission to move the system directory above the root, the folder was writable too. And I never had to use 777. 755 for directories and 644 for files did the job.

Comment: I have a couple of additional questions. In looking through my site I do not see a folder "db_cache" at the specified path. Just ee-version, magpie_cache, and page_cache.
1. What does this line of code do? 2. Do I need to create the folder manually?

Comment: @cscott, all subfolders of cache are created by the EECMS itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look to make it a little more dynamic (and legible) by using APPPATH:

```
$db['expressionengine']['cachedir'] = APPPATH."cache/db_cache/";
```

You still need to set 777 permissions on the cache/ directory but it will be writable when placed above the webroot.